Can I set the INSTALL_RPATH property for every target that links with my library in cmake?
Ideally, I would like to do something like this:
set_target_properties(<shared_lib_target> INTERFACE PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH <path>)

But the set_target_properties command does not accept INTERFACE as an option.
Is there some other way to do this?

RPATH-related options are not propagated during the linkage. You may set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH variable at the beginning of your project. So every created target with have INSTALL_RPATH property  being set to the value of the variable.
